# Feeding Wordpress blog entries to own website

Tags: wordpress, rss, blogs

I have some code which will feed through the ten most recent Wordpress blog posts through to my own non-Wordpress site. Is there any way to display the featured image assigned to a blog post? I have successfully echoed the blog title, date and body.

```
      <?php
        global $text, $maxchar, $end;
        function substrwords($text, $maxchar, $end='...') {
          if (strlen($text) > $maxchar || $text == '') {
            $words = preg_split('/\s/', $text);      
            $output = '';
            $i      = 0;
            while (1) {
              $length = strlen($output)+strlen($words[$i]);
              if ($length > $maxchar) {
                break;
              } else {
                $output .= " " . $words[$i];
                ++$i;
              }
            }
            $output .= $end;
          } else {
            $output = $text;
          }
          return $output;
        }

        $rss = new DOMDocument();
        $rss->load('http://myblog.wordpress.com/rss/'); // <-- Change feed to your site
        $feed = array();
        foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
          $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
          );
          array_push($feed, $item);
        }

        $limit = 10; // <-- Change the number of posts shown
        for ($x=0; $x<$limit; $x++) {
          $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
          $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
          $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
          $description = substrwords($description, 400);
          $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
          echo '<div style="margin-bottom:25px;">';
          echo '<h3><strong><a style="color: #139035;" href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a></strong></h3>';
          echo '<p><small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
          echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
          echo '<span> <strong><a target="_blank" style="color: #139035;" href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">Read blog ></span></strong>';
          echo '</div>';
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: WordPress default RSS feeds do not expose featured images. You'll need to extend the functionality of the RSS feed on the blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to add featured image into your RSS

```
function img_in_rss($content) {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
$content = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium') . $content;
}
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'img_in_rss');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'img_in_rss');
```

Comment: the add filter bit at the bottom is giving me an error

Comment: what error you getting? I tested it is adding featured image into feed.

Comment: I'm using CakePHP, the error I'm getting is 'Fatal Error
Error: Call to undefined function add_filter() ' .. where are you inserting this bit of code

Comment: I am so sorry, you need to add above code in WordPress theme's functions.php file , RSS is being generated by WP site, right? so we can add image only there.

Comment: Where can I find that file? I am not familiar with Wordpress and I'm having to set up a WP blog that feeds through to their website for a client

Comment: In your WordPress website, you must know your current theme being used then .. go to wp-content/themes/your-active-theme  in it you will have functions.php file